# Is there a way to lein Taamei Emes that includes mesharsim?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms, trop-cantillation, mishlei, job-iyov-book-of

I learned to lein Taamei Emes a few years ago using [this link](http://kinnor.com/Taamei_Emet/), which I found in a comment here on MY.

However, the tradition recorded there only takes the mafsikim into account, and all the mesharsim, with a couple of exceptions, are treated equally.  Some of the secondary stresses, like tzinoris, are completely ignored.  Does anyone have a way to lein that take ALL of the trop, or at least more of them, into account?

My primary motivation here is to get a sense of the grammar implied by the trop, which is very complicated as I found when writing [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99239/11532).  I'd prefer a real tradition if that exists, but I'd be ok with a method that's reconstructed or even just made up in a systematic way that respects the grammar.  (Of course, it should be honest about where it comes from.  I don't want another Yerushalmi Kodshim.)

Comment: Generally only Ashkenazim add tunes to conjunctive notes, so seemingly no, there is no tradition available at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA as I said, in the one I linked some of the notes don't seem to do anything, and they have to be there for some purpose.  Also there could be one made up.

Comment: For non ashkenazim meshartim do indeed do just about nothing. I'm not denying someone could make something up

Comment: @DoubleAA in the 21 books, they do indicate the stress, which I don't call "nothing" even if the exact identity of the symbol doesn't matter to non-Ashkenazim.  In Eme"s there are some symbols that don't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: In EMT [they indicate stress too](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97779/759). The only possible exception is the "Oleh". Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DoubleAA Tzinnoris?

Comment: An accent only used on secondary stresses. We know from 21 books too that some notes tend to develop fuller Meshartim on secondary accents on big words (eg. Zakef, Tevir)

Comment: @DoubleAA ok, but they're weird secondary stresses.  You'd never find a gaya on yud of יבשו (using the example you linked) in the 21 books.  To me that indicates that there has to have been some music that correlates to the stress, otherwise why would Eme"s be different than the rest.

Comment: We already know there had to have been music for all the Meshartim because why else have different ones at all. This isn't new. Ashkenazim had it. Others didn't (perhaps following other Trop systems like Bavel that didn't have Meshartim). All I said was you won't find any traditions about the music.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Max Tawil Tehillim Lesson- I" on this page:
http://www.pizmonim.org/section.php?maqam=Tehillim

There are other sources that explain the logic of the grammar better, but this is a "real tradition".  (The middle eastern communities have 3 separate tunes for Iyyov, Mishlei, and Tehillim by the way.  Eshet Hayil is read with the Mishlei tune on Erev Shabbat.)

Comment: Do they have tunes for conjunctive notes?

Comment: I can't say that it covers "all the mesharsim" as the question asked.  However, Tawil discusses each ta'am and explains which are emphasized and which aren't.  Consider too that it's possible that the conjunctive accents in some books never had musical notes specifically associated with them.

Comment: About how many conjunctive accents are assigned specific tunes? The question was particularly targeting that info so please include it. And while it is possible they never had tunes it's not particularly likely since then they'd have had no purpose.

Comment: I asked a Syrian friend once if I could hear him lein Tehillim, and (at least his version of) their tradition doesn't have a tune for the mesharsim.  But I can give it a try.

Comment: Yes, but the question is also qualified by "my primary motivation here is to get a sense of the grammar implied by the trope".  I have pretty good intuition for the Emes grammar after hearing these recordings.  As to the second part, when I learned to lein, I was told that ta'amim and the music attached to the ta'amim are two different things; sometimes a ta'am has a specific tune, but not always.  I learned to "lein" for months before I was given an tune to use.  Maybe different communities approach the subject differently.

Comment: Do you have a good sense of the difference between a mercha and a munach, for instance?  I don't.

Comment: Yes, I know the rules for what goes where (except in rare cases).  But in terms of music, I think of the entire disjunctive block as a single musical pattern.  For example, munach+zaqef qaton is one pattern; Mercha+tipcha is another pattern.  If there is a school of trope where conjunctive accents have their own isolated pattern, that would be news to me.

Comment: I know about munach+zakef katon and mercha+tipcha, but that's in the 21 books.  What about mercha+sof pasuk and munach+sof pasuk in taamei emes?  They're both fairly common.  You get similar things in the 21 books, like the conjunctives before a zarka, but they're more rare and in any case you get a sense of them from learning to lein.