# What is the correct vowelization for the word יעמד in ויקרא ט”ז verse 10?

Tags: torah-reading, vowels-nekudot, parshat-acharei-mot

(In the fourth aliyah of shacharit Yom Kippur.)

All the sources I have put a chataf qamatz under the 'ayin. The question is what is under the yod: qamatz or qamatz qatan. I have sources that show both possibilities, but I do not have definitive texts that mark qamatz qatan. What do those texts say?

Comment: "definitive texts that mark qamatz qatan" I've never heard of such a thing

Comment: https://hebrew-academy.org.il/2010/03/24/צָהֳרַי%D6%B4ם-נָעֳמ%D6%B4י-הגיית-קמץ-לפני-חט/ (@DoubleAA)

Comment: FWIW my Tikkun Simanim does not mark a kamatz katan under the yod.

Comment: It's probably somewhere in the same article I linked here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99239/11532

Comment: Having heard this \`aliyah read in many shuls (Sepharadi and Ashkenazi), I’ve only ever heard it pronounced ya-oh-ma-d.